# Unexplained document height and scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css, dom, height, viewport

We're making a responsive site that shows/hides page parts depending on the browser size and I'm getting a weird discrepancy from the document height and its children height.

At full resolution everything works fine so:

- **$(document).height() = 955**
- **$(window).height() = 955**
- **$('html').height() = 955**

But when I resize the window

- **$(document).height() = 801**
- **$(window).height() = 702**
- **$(html).height() = 702**

The document is 100px higher than all its children! I accurately inspected all the children (HTML, body, inner divs...) and not a single one is more than 702px high.

How is that? Has anyone got any clue?? It's driving me mad!
Thank you :)

Comment: Which browser ? Can you copy the HTML/CSS for <html>, <body>, and <body> direct children ?

Comment: Can you post  jfiddle or codepen of your example?

Comment: It happened in every browser but I found out what it was. Check answer below and thanks anyway for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox 3D view I found out that the border of one of the divs caused the scrollbars to appear! I still don't understand why the document was 100px higher since the border was just of a few pixels..

I really recommend this Firefox feautre since it shows very clearly items position inside the page and helped me with this problem!